# Java ObjectTool

Tags: java

What is meant by Java ObjectTool ?
I'm studying the Fundamentals of Java track (SL-110-SE6) and multiple times it mentioned in exercises to explore the Java objects using Viewing Arrays Using the ObjectTool, I can not I searched in oracle.java website but I can not find any documentation, Also Google I do not think I can find what they mean, any Ideas ?

Comment: Do you use a particular IDE? It is probably a module in the tool (IDE to inspect the Objects)